# Does Sitecore.Jobs.JobManager persist job data to the Tasks or EventQueue table within the Core DB?

Tags: events

**For Sitecore 9.2 are Jobs persisted within the Core DB or are they simply stored in memory?**

I have an event handler that executes on `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` to start the Job, but it always checks to see if there is an instance of that Job already running. I'm wondering if something was not properly cleared up on the CD server and so there is somehow a 'dead' Job hanging around, which now prevents subsequent execution. Is there any way to manually inspect the current Jobs on a CD server?

Comment: You have a few questions here. Per your title “does SC persist jobs in the core event queue?”- no. The event queue is one way communication. One server (CM most often) inserts events into the queue and other servers read them. But the calling server does not know who consumed them. They are unrelated to jobs. For jobs, I always assumed they were managed entirely in memory. I’ve never come across a start/running/finished mechanism in the database. You would need to do that yourself.

Comment: TDS used to do this whenever you used the tds update package. It writes an Enum to the core db properties table for running/finished etc. This was because an update package could cause an app pool recycle which then prevents post-install steps from running. There was an accompanying processor in <initialization> that would check for the Enum and finish the process. Sounds convoluted but it’s correct :D